# An identity about the Gamma function

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

When I do some numerical test, I can get:

$$\frac{2^{2a+1}\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(a+\frac32)}{\Gamma(2a+2)}=\sqrt{\pi}.$$

Here $a$ is to be taken such that the Gamma function well-defined.

My question is that is there is a way to prove this identity.

I tried to apply the identity $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$ but no further result.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as the **duplication formula** for the Gamma function. It is commonly written as
$$
\Gamma(2z) = \pi^{-1/2}2^{2z-1}\Gamma(z) \Gamma(z+1/2)
$$
and appears as formula 5.5.5 in the [NIST handbook](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5).

Comment: Proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846626/duplication-formula-for-gamma-function) & [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Legendre's_Duplication_Formula).